# parametric form of vector

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

[image]

I am having trouble understanding what the question is asking at this point, I have solved the first parts correctly and was wondering if I could get help as to how to solve x=x(t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** It is finished, you have already done it, $x(t)=2-5t$.  I do not think you will have trouble with $y(t)$ or $z(t)$!

Comment: Most definitely! Just saw how to do it! Thank you once again :)